# React:- Unable to get updates state value in multiple functions on OnClick

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am building a stepper component in which if a step is marked as skip , on hit of next the stepper should check if the next step is skipped go to next further.

In The below code on clicking card skipStep executed which should set skip to true for platform key ( this is working ), changeProperty is executed it should set value of flow key to web ( this is working ), now when next function is executed I need next position of country as platform is skipped, that part is not working.

In next function I am not able to get the updated values of sortedSteps , getting initial values where skip true is not present.

```
const [steps, setSteps] = React.useState({
    email: {
        position: 0,
        label: "Email",
        optional: false,
        value: null,
        skip: false
    },
    flow: {
        position: 1,
        optional: false,
        label: "Flow",
        value: null,
        skip: false
    },
    platform: {
        position: 2,
        optional: true,
        label: "Platform",
        value: null,
        skip: false
    },
    country: {
        position: 3,
        optional: false,
        label: "Country",
        value: null,
        skip: false
    },
    campaign: {
        position: 4,
        optional: false,
        label: "Campaign",
        value: null,
        skip: false
    },
    offer: {
        position: 5,
        optional: false,
        label: "Offer",
        value: null,
        skip: false
    },
    done: {
        position: 6,
        optional: false,
        label: "Done",
        value: null,
        skip: false
    }
})

const sortedSteps = React.useMemo(() => {
    console.log(steps)
    let sorted_keys = Object.keys(steps).sort((a, b) => steps[a].position - steps[b].position);
return sorted_keys.map((key) => ({id: key, ...steps[key]}))
}, [steps])

const skipStep = async (keys) => {
// async function skipStep(keys) {
    let resetSkip = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(steps).map(([key, val]) => [key, {...val, skip: false}]))
setSteps(resetSkip)
if(keys.length > 0) keys.map(e => {
    setSteps(steps=> ({...steps, [e]: {...steps[e], skip: true}}))
})
}

const changeProperty = async (evt) => {
// const changeProperty = (evt) => {
    let id = evt.target.name
    let value = evt.target.value
    setSteps(steps=> ({...steps, [id]: {...steps[id], value: value}}))
}
const nextStep =(n)=> {
    console.log(sortedSteps)
    console.log(abc)
    let nextStep = sortedSteps.slice(n+1, sortedSteps.length).find(elem => !elem.skip)
setStep(nextStep.position)
scrollToStep(nextStep.position)
}


<Card raised=

    disabled={f.disabled}
onClick={async (e) => {
    setIsTest(f.isTest)
await skipStep(['platform']).then()
await  changeProperty({target: {name:"flow", value: 'web'}}).then()
nextStep(1);
}}
>
```